# Is it good practice to create type dynamically for each new user registered and track their data in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I am creating an app where i need store large dataset for each user, so i decided to use Elasticsearch.

Is it good practice to create **TYPE** dynamically for each new user registered and track their data in that type in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. Since you're tracking users, you probably need a single `users` index (or a few time-based ones) with a single mapping type (what you call a TYPE) containing all the user fields you want to store/index/track.

It is a waste of resources to create an index and/or type per user as each index contains a few shards (5 by default) each of which is a full-fledge Lucene index consuming CPU, memory and network bandwidth.